# How to test a function within an if statement in catch block using jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this code:

**handler.js**

```
try {
    const body = await calculateSum(event, context);

    return body;
  } catch (err) {

    if (err.response) {
      if (err.response.status === 400) {
        throw new BadRequest('Invalid parameters');
      }

      if (err.response.status === 401 || err.response.status === 403) {
        invokeLambda({
          FunctionName: context.GET_TOKEN,
          InvocationType: 'Event'
        });
      }
    }
    throw new InternalServerError();
  }
}
```

and I want to unit test using jest that invokeLambda was called with certain parameters. Anyone know how I can do that? I did the following but got an error:

**handler.test.js**

```
calculateSum.default.mockRejectedValueOnce({
      err: {
        response: {
          status: 401
        }
      }
    });

invokeLambda.mockResolvedValueOnce();
    await handler({
      quantity: 2,
      price: "34.00"
      },
      { GET_TOKEN: 'GET_TOKEN' }
    );

    expect(invokeLambda).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      FunctionName: 'GET_TOKEN',
      InvocationType: 'Event'
    });
```

I've mocked calculateSum and invokeLambda.I get the error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined`

Comment: your `err` object in exception is undefined. That's probably because you are calling `mockRejectedValueOnce` without any parameter. Check the jest documents, that can help https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockrejectedvalueoncevalue

Comment: I changed it to this now:

```
    calculateSum.default.mockRejectedValueOnce({
      err: {
        response: {
          status: 401
        }
      }
    });
```

But now it jumps to internal server error O_O

Comment: did it worked? or you still have the same issue? Make sure that object that you are passing inside the function follows the expected structure

Comment: I get `InternalServerError: Internal Server Error`

Comment: that's possibly because your `err.response` is false or undefined. Can you please add the updated code in the question

Comment: Just updated it

Answer (score 0):

I believe `mockRejectedValueOnce` should pass an object as below

```
calculateSum.default.mockRejectedValueOnce({
  response: {
    status: 401
  }
});
```

Key `err` is not required as that's the name of variable holding the error object

Comment: I did that but I still get Internal Server Error :(

Comment: did you tried printing the object (using `console.info`) in the catch block of code? what are you getting as `err`?

Comment: I had to wrap my handler call in a try catch in the test. I will answer this question now with a solution. I am not a fan of doing try catch inside a test so want to see an alternative solution 

Comment: Just posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

So I had to wrap my handler call in a try catch block like this:

```
calculateTax.default.mockRejectedValueOnce({
    response: {
    status: 401
  }
});

invokeLambda.mockResolvedValueOnce();

try {
  await handler({
      quantity: 2,
      price: "34.00"
      },
      { GET_TOKEN: 'GET_TOKEN' }
    );
} catch (e) {
 // Blah blah
}

expect(invokeLambda).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      FunctionName: 'GET_TOKEN',
      InvocationType: 'Event'
    });
```

It's because we don't return anything in the `if (err.response.status === 401 etc` block so it will keep running until it reaches the Internal Service Error exception